# Como colocar área de seleção (móvel) para foto tiradas

Tags: android

Gostaria de sabe como faço para logo após tirar uma foto e pegar o arquivo e carregar está foto, criar uma área de seleção da foto ao estilo foto de perfil do whatsapp, e depois salvar apenas esse pedaço como sendo a imagem.

Exemplos: [image: Marcação grande]

[image: marcação pequena]

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você pode usar estas lib para facilitar o processo https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3182, https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2791 
ou pode fazer usando o bitmap

```
Bitmap Bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, 0, 0, originalBmp.getWidth(), originalBmp.getHeight()-10);
```